# connection string injection

Tags: ninject

I am trying to learn Ninject and started with what I thought is very simple thing. Can't make it work. Obviously, I am missing something basic.

So, I have this little console application that listens for WCF calls on a certain port and saves data that come via WCF to a database. There are 3 projects in the solution: 1. data access library, 2. WCF stuff and 3. console acting as a host. Ninject is not used yet. So the dependencies between projects are like this: 3 -> 2 -> 1

I want to start with injecting connection string that console host takes from its config into data access library. Googling for ninjection of connection string brought some examples, but they are not complete.

One of the examples suggested to bind in the host's Main() like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new StandardKernel().Bind<ConnectionStringProvider>().ToConstant(
    new ConnectionStringProvider { ConnectionString = Config.ConnectionString });
}
```

where ConnectionStrinProvider is a simple class that contains only one property ConnectionString. What I can't figure out is how do I instantiate ConnectionStrinProvider in the data access library. I tried

```
var csprovider = new StandardKernel().Get<ConnectionStringProvider>();
```

it doesn't work - meaning that it returns new instance of the provider instead of the one that was created during binding. I also tried to add .InSingletonScope() to the binding, with the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep a reference to the kernel you set up. It doesn't work if you instantiate it every time.

```
public static IKernel Ninject {get; private set;}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Ninject =  new StandardKernel()
    Ninject.Bind<ConnectionStringProvider>().ToConstant(
    new ConnectionStringProvider { ConnectionString = Config.ConnectionString });
}
```

On the consummer side, you can call the `Ninject` static property on your main.

Obvious note aside: this is sample code, on production code you may want to make a better design for that global static variable.

Comment: This will create reverse dependency from data access library to console app (1 -> 3), which, in my opinion, would defeats the purpose of using Ninject in the first place (which is to decrease coupling).

Comment: True. that was the obvious note all about. `StandarKernel` ctor provides an overload for configuration modules. Each layer in your software should provide one or more of this config modules. As Kirk above said, you don't need/want to reference the kernel directly on layer 1 to ask for services, the services should be injected to 1.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel is what keeps track of all the bindings for you.  However, you are creating a new instance each time.  That won't work.  Instead, create the kernel and then store it off (here I'm storing it off in a local variable, but you'd probably want to store it in a field in some class):

```
var connectionStringProvider = new ConnectionStringProvider { ConnectionString = Config.ConnectionString };
var kernel = new StandardKernel().Bind<ConnectionStringProvider>().ToConstant(connectionStringProvider);
```

Now obtain instances by accessing the existing kernel.

```
var csprovider = kernel.Get<ConnectionStringProvider>();
```

That being said, using it in this fashion is the wrong way to go about it, as this pattern is known as a service locator pattern, which is the antitheses of dependency injection.  Generally speaking, you have a top-level class (for example, your application class with the `Main` method) that is either obtained via `Kernel.Get` or injected via `Kernel.Inject`, and all other dependencies are injected normally through constructors or `[Inject]`'ed properties.

Also, there are [usually plugins available](http://www.ninject.org/extensions.html) for most situations so that you don't have to instantiate the kernel yourself.  However, I'm not aware of one for console apps.

Comment: Can you provide a code example of how to achieve my goal without going wrong way about it? Examples I have seen so far bind stuff in Main and resolve dependencies in other modules via calling kernel.Get() without explaining where kernel variable comes from. Exposing it as a static member of some class in console app will create dependency from data access library to console app (1 -> 3), which, in my opinion, would defeats the purpose of using Ninject in the first place (which is to decrease coupling).

Comment: I'm happy to provide a more complete example, but can you elaborate on how you are interacting with your data access library?  Can you show me the code (by editing your question) where you instantiate/invoke stuff in the DAL?  Also, can you provide a bit more context (like the surrounding class) around the line that you have getting the `ConnectionStringProvider`?